# OMXplayer play video with no sound and mp3 at 2/4 times the speed

Tags: pi-3, audio, raspbian-stretch, alsa, omxplayer

Using a USB sound card, I'm trying to play mp3 files, with the default *omxplayer*. But although all other software works fine, *omxplayer* play my mp3 files at **2x speed**, sometimes even 4 times.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that those mp3 files are using a non-standard `sample-rate`, that cannot be set in *omxplayer*. Any sample-rate below the *standard* (CD quality) of **44100 Hz**, will be ignored and thus the audio data conversion will go through the data faster.

```bsh
$ ffprobe quaterSR.mp3 2>&1 | grep Stream
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s

$ ffprobe halfSR.mp3 2>&1 | grep Stream
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, stereo, s16p, 56 kb/s

$ ffprobe normalSR.mp3 2>&1 | grep Stream
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```

Similarly, if the *sample-rate* is higher than **44100** Hz, the sound will be slowed down, when played.

Comment: This was actually a bug in the *omxplayer*, that has recently [been fixed](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/commit/68961b36a1b11f5ef46ac14950b8c5c6ec5fdd47). Hopefully also part of the next Raspbian updates.